# TYPO3 Custom Validation not working

Tags: php, validation, typo3, extbase

My Custom Extbase Validation is not working.
I get following Error.

Version TYPO3 7.6.16

I'm trying to validate the input.

```
Invalid validate annotation in VENDOR\ex\Domain\Model\GpSubscriber::salutation: Could not resolve class name for validator ""
```

My Model GpSubscriber.php

```
<?php
namespace VENDOR\ex\Domain\Model;

/**
* GpSubscriber
*/
class GpSubscriber extends \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\DomainObject\AbstractEntity
{
/**
 * salutation
 *
 * @var string
 * @validate \VENDOR\ex\Domain\Validator\SalutationValidator
 */
protected $salutation = '';
```

My Validator SalutationValidator.php

```
<?php
namespace VENDOR\ex\Domain\Validator;


class SalutationValidator extends \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Validation\Validator\AbstractValidator {
public function isValid($value) {
    if ($value == 'false') {
        $this->addError('error.');
        return FALSE;
    }
    return TRUE;
}
}
```

Where is my Problem?

Comment: Looks good, did you clear the cache completely?

Comment: Yes, i cleared all the cache in the install tool.

Comment: Weird. I see no obvious mistake.

Comment: Only place to find that error message in core is `\TYPO3\CMS\Form\Controller\FrontendController` as of TYPO3 7.x. Is that your version and are you inheriting from extension `form`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I dumped the autoload cache by disabling the extension and activated it again. After that everything was working

Answer (score 1):

Try to move your class SalutationValidator to extension/Validation/Validator/SalutationValidator.php

```
<?php
namespace VENDOR\ex\Domain\Model;

/**
* GpSubscriber
*/
class GpSubscriber extends \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\DomainObject\AbstractEntity
{

    /**
     * salutation
     *
     * @var string
     * @validate \VENDOR\ex\Validation\Validator\SalutationValidator
     */
    protected $salutation = '';
```

```
<?php
namespace VENDOR\ex\Validation\Validator;

class SalutationValidator extends \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Validation\Validator\AbstractValidator {

    /**
     * The given value is valid if it contains not more then max items
     *
     * @param mixed $value The value that should be validated
     * @return void
     */
    public function isValid($value) {
        if ($value == 'false') {
            $this->addError('error.');
            return FALSE;
        }
    return TRUE;
    }
}
```

Deactivate and activate again your extension and classes will reloaded.

Answer (score 0):

`@validate` is deprecated since version 9.3. In 7+ use `@TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Annotation\Validate` instead.

Example:

```
use TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Annotation as Extbase;
use TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\DomainObject\AbstractEntity;

class GpSubscriber extends AbstractEntity {

    /**
     * @var string
     * @Extbase\Validate("VENDOR\ex\Domain\Validator\SalutationValidator")
     */
    protected $title;

...
}
```

This way, you can still store your validator in `Model/Validator` directory.

If you choose to store your validator under `Validation/Validator` in your extension, you may choose to use `@Extbase\Validate("VENDOR.ex:Salutation")` or `@Extbase\Validate("VENDOR\ex\Validation\Validator\SalutationValidator")` to access your validator.

**Notes:**

- Ensure your validator namespace in `@Extbase\Validate` doesn't start
  with a slash.
- Ensure getters and setters for all defined properties.
- Ensure all properties (fields from view) in your model (in this case
  class `GpSubscriber`) are defined.

**More information:**

- [See deprecation notice.](https://docs.typo3.org/c/typo3/cms-core/master/en-us/Changelog/9.3/Deprecation-83167-ReplaceValidateWithTYPO3CMSExtbaseAnnotationValidate.html)